# Regex for number comparison?

Tags: php, regex, numbers, compare, permutation

I would like to perform regex to return true/false if the input 5 digit from input matching data in database, no need to cater of the sequence, but need the exact numbers.

Eg: In database I have 12345

When I key in a 5 digit value into search, I want to find out whether it is matching the each number inside the 12345.

If I key in 34152- it should return true

If I key in 14325- it should return true

If I key in 65432- it should return false

If I key in 11234- it should return false

Eg: In database I have 44512

If I key in 21454- it should return true

If I key in 21455- it should return false

How to do this using php with regex

Comment: Please don't use a regex for this. It's going to come out hideously complicated. Rather count the digits and compare explicitly.

Comment: Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values. Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Answer (score 3):

This is a way avoiding regex

```
<?php
function cmpkey($a,$b){
  $aa =  str_split($a); sort($aa);
  $bb =  str_split($b); sort($bb);
  return ( implode("",$aa) == implode("",$bb));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not going to be a trivial regex, I can tell you that.  You **could** do something like this:

```
$chars = count_chars($input, 1);
$numbers = array();
foreach ($chars as $char => $frequency) {
    if (is_numeric(chr($char))) {
        $numbers[chr($char)] = $frequency;
    }
}
// that converts "11234" into array(1 => 2, 2 => 1, 3 => 1, 4 => 1)
```

Now, since MySQL doesn't support assertions in regex, you'll need to do this in multiple regexes:

```
$where = array();
foreach ($numbers AS $num => $count) {
    $not = "[^$num]";
    $regex = "^";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $regex .= "$not*$num";
    }
    $regex .= "$not*";
    $where[] = "numberField REGEXP '$regex'";
}

$where = '((' . implode(') AND (', $where).'))';
```

That'll produce:

```
( 
        (numberField REGEXP '^[^1]*1[^1]*1[^1]*$') 
    AND 
        (numberField REGEXP '^[^2]*2[^2]*$')
    AND
        (numberField REGEXP '^[^3]*3[^3]*$')
    AND
        (numberField REGEXP '^[^4]*4[^4]*$')
)
```

That should do it for you.

It's not pretty, but it should take care of all of the possible permutations for you, assuming that your stored data format is consistent...

But, depending on your needs, you should try to pull it out and process it in PHP.  In which case the regex would be far simpler:

```
^(?=.*1.*1})(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4)\d{5}$
```

Or, you could also pre-sort the number before you insert it.  So instead of inserting `14231`, you'd insert `11234`.  That way, you always know the sequence is ordered properly, so you just need to do `numberField = '11234'` instead of that gigantic beast above...

Comment: Care to explain the -1?  What's wrong with any of what I posted?  I did include the **best** possible option which is to pre-sort the number so it's a trivial string comparison.  And it's doing it in the database, so if it's a filter you're not transferring everything to MySQL to do the filtering...

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
^(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5).{5}$
```

This will get much more complicated, when you have duplicate numbers. 
You really should not do this with regex. =)

Comment: MySQL does not support assertions.  If it did, it would be easy.  But it does not.  So that means you either need to do an abuse like I did in my answer, or pull it out and do the check with preg in php...

Comment: @ircmaxell: MySQL is not mentioned in the question. It is tagged php.